# How can I cache the marshalled SOAP XML generated by Apache CXF for a particular Java Object to improve performance?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, cxf

In my application, we have a webservice method called getFoo() which returns a Foo object.  The **getFoo() method is called several hundred times a second**.  The Foo object is Marshalled from our Java object to the SOAP XML response using Apache CXF.

**From profiling our application, we determined that the marshalling of this object (java object -> soap encoded xml) is the single greatest consumer of CPU cycles.** and since our Foo object isn't changing very often, remarshalling this object each time is unnecessary.

**I figured this is a common optimization and wondered how others have addressed it.**
I briefly looked at the CXF docs and there is a Marshall interceptor which I could probably make use of.  I could create a Map which could map Foo objects to the XML encoded version.  But, then a few other issues come up like how do you remove objects from this Map once they are no longer needed etc.  It'd be nice if there was built in support for somehow detecting changes to the object and re-marshalling... Nothing impossible, but didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

**EDIT (6/16/09)**: Have made some progress by making a custom BareOutInterceptor and modifying the Interceptor chain to call the custom one.  The custom adds some additional logic to only call the "writeParts(....)" method which performs the marshalling only the once for a given java object.  Will post solution once finished.  Also, I renamed the question.

Comment: Is there an Apache CXF expert on SO who can tell us how to add a custom marshaller in the outbound interceptor chain?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, not exactly the answer you are looking for, but anyway: The reason that REST is used in Webservices with high traffic (e.g. Google), is that REST is designed to be cacheable - whereas SOAP is just NOT designed to be cachable.

SOAP is basically based on (per HTTP definition) non-cacheable POST requests, and REST uses GET - which is easy to cache.

You would have to inspect the SOAP (POST) request before it goes to the actual Webservice - i.e. using a proxy. "Standard" proxies are usually unaware of SOAP syntax.

[IBM's WebSphere Application Server though can do that](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v5r1//index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rdyn_webservicescaching.html)

Regards, 
 Olaf

Comment: @Olaf When the webservice method is called... I still want to apply some business logic to determine the contents of the Foo Object.  So, it's not as simple as for a given post return y.  But, typically the contents are exactly the same for 99% of the users calling the service.  So, i'd like to cache the marshalled result somehow for the object.  Thanks for your post though the article was interesting.

Comment: I don't know if there is a ready to use implementation/example for that, but you could use a (slightly modified) Memoization Pattern implementation for that.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict requirement in SOAP that you need to use a framework like CXF to handle the server or client SOAP endpoints.  We just ran into client thread deadlocks when using an Axis 1.4-based SOAP client to talk to an Axis 1.1-based server, and fixed them by ditching Axis and making the requests in hand-written code.  We had to lie to the Axis server by telling it we still had an Axis client, but felt no remorse!  ;-)

Similarly, you should be able to bypass CXF and generate SOAP responses in your own handwritten java code.  Then you can use a Map to cache your marshalled (unparsed, serialized) XML strings and eliminate this hotspot.

Strongly agree with Olaf on REST: if you fully leverage HTTP, then all this caching happens for free in all the intermediate caches between your server and your clients.  That's certainly something to consider for new services.

Update: CXF has the notion of customizable [interceptor chains](http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/interceptors.html).  One type of outbound interceptor is for the MARSHAL phase, so it sounds like you could add this cache there without having to ditch CXF.  Perhaps a CXF expert can verify that for us?

Comment: @Jim Ferrans - We have a number of methods and complex object which would make maintaining handwritten code unfeasible.  I was hoping to find an example of how to use interceptor chains to cache the method body component of the soap message.  I haven't found any good examples in the Apache docs.

Answer (score 0):

> The Foo object is Marshalled from our Java object to the SOAP XML response using Apache CXF.
>   ..
>   the single greatest consumer of CPU cycles. and since our Foo object isn't changing very often, remarshalling this object each time is unnecessary.

Does the client application need to know of changes in Foo instantly or as soon as possible?

Why not cache it on the consumer/client side? A design where you are calling the same web service method hundreds of times per second probably isn't the best.

Comment: We have thousands of unique clients calling the getFoo Method approximately once every 20s.  Therefore, we can't cache on the client side.